# Brew install libpcap does not provide binaries

Tags: libpcap, packet-sniffers

Stupid question: I'm trying to install libpcap on my macOS (Big Sur) using brew. I've executed "brew install libpcap". Now, I would imagine that I could now run libpcap out of the box, but it tell me that `libpcap: command not found`. brew tells me this:

> If you need to have libpcap first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpcap/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/michal/.bash_profile

Now I've checkd that it's in the bash_profile, and it doesn't work. So I check the actual package, and in it, there is no binary file. The binary is also not in `usr/local/bin`.

brew furthermore tells me that

> libpcap is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local
> because macOS already provides this software and installing another
> version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

but I don't really know what this means, seeing that I cannot find it anywhere.

What is going on here? Where is it installed, and how do I run that program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TCPDUMP](https://www.tcpdump.org/):

> ... libpcap, a portable C/C++ library for network traffic capture.

libpcap is a library, not a program.